# Does the keyextractor for SectionList need to return a unique value for the whole data or just the section?

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

The keyextractor on the SectionList defines a signature that only accepts the item.  Does the keyextractor for SectionList need to return a unique value for the whole data or just the section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used to extract a unique key for a given item at the specified index. Key is used for caching and as the react key to track item re-ordering. The default extractor checks item.key, then item.id, and then falls back to using the index, like React does.

##### It is unique per section. It needs to be unique if you want to prevent any unwanted UI flicks during re-rendering.